# How to add ng-app into a slim template

Tags: angularjs, slim-lang

I need to add my ng-app=myApp into my application.html.slim. Im having problems that I can not find blogs on how to do this and its not in the slim docs. I have to put my ng-app in this file. How do insert it?

```
doctype html
head
  title PlanoX
  = stylesheet_link_tag("application", media: "all")
  = javascript_include_tag("application")
  = csrf_meta_tags
  = favicon_link_tag('favicon_64x64.ico')
  = javascript_include_tag "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"
  = javascript_include_tag "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular-resource.min.js"
  meta[name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"]

body.default

  = render("layouts/header")
  = yield
  = render("layouts/footer")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used slim, I just looked at their [docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/slim/frames#Attributes)

> **Attributes**
>
> You write attributes directly after the tag. For normal text attributes you must use double " or single quotes ' (Quoted attributes).

```
a href="http://slim-lang.com" title='Slim Homepage' Goto the Slim homepage
```

Since ng-app is just a tag attribute, you can do something like:

```
body.default ng-app="myApp"
```

Comment: To be fair, OP was looking for an answer in a blog :P

Comment: I think the problem is that im not overly familiar with slim either, we only have one doc in our project thats slim and i normally dont work with the front end. Plus when i was going through the docs i was searching for ng-app and angular, obviously not the way to go, but thank you for helping. The angular still does not work for the project, but at least its stopped throwing back errors. Thanks.